# Microsoft office 2013 excel and adding hours and minuts

Tags: excel

i am using window 7 with Microsoft office 2013.

i got excel to calculate hours per day correctly but when i try to add the total hours i have worked excel get it wrong for example 
the formula i am using is =($G4-$F4)

start    stop       Total for the day
09:12   17:00       7.48
08:18   17:00       8.42
08:36   17:00       8.24
08:42   17:00       8.18
08:30   17:00       8.30

The problem is when i use SUM i get a total of  17:42

thank you for all your help

Comment: 09:12 17:00 7.48 08:18 17:00 8.42 08:36 17:00 8.24 08:42 17:00 8.18 08:30 17:00 8.30, is data in two pair, or saperate data ?

Answer (score 1):

use sum function.

```
=SUM(column ranges)
```